# Concatenate two (or more) strings and result in the same string regardless of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate some strings into single string. (ex: "Pen" and "Apple" -> "PenApple")
But, I want the outputting string to be the same regardless of the order they're concatenated in.

Each string contain non-Unicode characters.

If the implementation of `newConcat("Pen", "Apple")` outputs `"PenApple"`
then `newConcat("Pen", "Apple") === newConcat("", "PenApple")`

and likewise, `newConcat("Pen", "Apple") === newConcat("", "ApplePen")` then `newConcat("Pen", "Apple")` must output `"ApplePen"`

In general, these test cases needs to be true as well:

```
newConcat("Pen", "Apple") === newConcat("Apple", "Pen"); // true
newConcat("Pen", "Apple") === newConcat("_P3n", "_App13"); // false

newConcat("Pen", "Pineapple", "Apple", "Pen") === newConcat("Apple", "Pen", "Pen", "Pineapple"); // true
```

What I've come up with so far, is to put the strings in an array, sort it, then return it joined as string.

```
function newConcat( ...strings ) {
    const newArray = []
    newArray.push(...strings)
    return newArray.sort().join("") 
}
```

I want to know if there's a better way to do this than to sort the strings inside an array. What if I want to control what order they should be put together.

Comment: Should `newConcat("", "PenPineappleApplePen") === newConcat("", "APPPaeeeeeillnnnpppp")` be true? If not, then your test cases (the last one in particular) seem inconsistent.

Comment: Are there any conditions for the order because now I am thinking its just plain random

Comment: `newConcat("Pen", "Apple"); //  how come this outputs "PenApple"` when you're sorting the values in `newConcat` ?

Comment: My bad. You're right that it is inconsistent. I have removed the last line in the test cases. @JosephSible

Comment: Why do you want to do this? i.e. what other properties should the function have? Is it okay if `f("hello", "world") === f("hellow", "orld")`? Is it okay if that’s only not the case with high probability, like for a hash function?

Comment: @Ry- I was curious if many unique identifiers can be put together to form a super unique identifier where the previous IDs can be easily derived from the new super ID. Say a room would have a super ID made from the IDs of its occupants and the super ID will change as new occupants arrive. f("hello", "world") === f("hellow", "orld") only if f("hellow", "world") === "helloworld"

Comment: @Terry: I don’t understand that last bit, but is there anything wrong with your solution, then? It seems neat enough to me (although you can simplify it by returning `strings.sort().join('')` directly – and maybe it should have a delimiter that isn’t found in IDs). When would controlling the order be helpful?

Comment: @Terry, if you want `f("hello", "world") === f("helloworl", "d") `, then your solution with sorting won't work. In this case, it will sort `d` before `helloworl`

Comment: @Ry- Sorry, I was confused with the case you mentioned and didn't explain clearly. To clarify, `f("hello", world") should not equal f("hellow", "orld")`. I realized the case where they are equal is if the function sorts by alphabetical order where both would output "helloworld". Thank you for the simplification.

Comment: @CodeManiac I realized I shouldn't have dictated the output. I meant that `newConcat("Pen", "Apple");` can potentially output `"PenApple" or "ApplePen" depending on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the results as an array and order it before returning like this.

I hope this helps!

```js
    function newConcat(array) {
    array.sort();
    var concat = "";
    for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
       concat = concat +array[i]
       }

    return concat
    }

    console.log(newConcat(["Pen","Apple"]));
    console.log(newConcat(["Pen","Apple"])===newConcat(["Pen","Apple"]));
    console.log(newConcat(["Pen","Apple"])===newConcat(["_P3n","_App13"]));

    console.log(newConcat(["Pen", "Pineapple", "Apple", "Pen"])===newConcat(["Apple", "Pen", "Pen", "Pineapple"]));
```